# How to read file from share folder by C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

I want to use FileStream(C#) to read file in share folder in another PC(windows)

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
```

But 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'

```
filePath = "\\sharefolder\test.csv"
filePath = @"\\sharefolder\test.csv"
filePath = "\\\\sharefolder\\test.csv"
```

(these 3 ways are all FileNotFoundException)

I can access this file  by windows Explorer

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.. or possibly CAS. Have you tried running VIsual Studio as Administrator when testing this?

Comment: Your call to `new FileStream` uses a variable named `filePath`, but the other three code lines use a variable named `filaPath`. You might want to [edit] and fix that by replacing them with the **real variables and content** you've tried; when you make up stuff for your question, it often hides the real problem.

Comment: a little mistake, "\\\\sharefolder\\test.csv" works now.

Comment: That's a perfect example of what @KenWhite is talking about. If that works.. then `@"\\sharefolder\test.csv"` should have also worked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a typo, and therefore has no future value here.

Comment: What was this little mistake? If it was that typo I would have to agree that this question should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd set those items to be copied into the bin folder. Right click in `solution explorer/navigator`, choose `properties` and set `Copy to output directory` to something different.

```
DirectoryInfo diSrc = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Ip_Address_OfComputer\D(D or c Directory)\Shared folder");
DirectoryInfo diDest = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\New folder at your machine");
CopyDirectory(diSrc, diDest, "174");
```

Then you can read the the file.